# Flask page receiving GET request instead of POST even if Ajax is sending POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, post, flask-wtforms

I don't know why, but I cannot receive POST method, instead I receive the GET method that I placed at the end of this post. I can't wrap my head around about what I am doing wrong. I suppose the interference must be with **< form id="myForm" >** Which should just call the function **modify_event** that would then send the POST request. So on the top of my head the solution would be replacing it and calling the function in another way, like the ***onclick for submit***, but apparently it doesn't work?

Thanks everyone.

**JS and HTML code :**

```
<form id ="myForm" onsubmit="modify_event()">
      <!-- MODIFY EVENT MODAL -->
      <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="startdate" class="form-label">New date</label>
            <!-- HERE I PASS THE DATE -->      
                {{form1.startdate(class_='form-control')}}
                </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                Close
                </button>
                {{form1.submit()}}  
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

<script>
  function modify_event() {
    var value = document.getElementById('startdate').value;
    $.ajax({
              url: "/modify_appointment",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                  new_date : value,
                  id: evId
              },
              success: function () {
                alert("Modified");
              }
          });
      }
```

**Python backend code :**

```
#Declaring the class 
class InfoForm(FlaskForm):
    startdate = DateTimeLocalField('Start date', format='%m-%d-%Y %h:%M', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

#HERE IS WHERE I INITIALIZE THE FORM
@app.route('/')
def appointments():
    startdate = None
    form1 = InfoForm()
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute("select * from Appuntamento ORDER BY Data ASC")
    if result > 0:
        appuntamenti = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return render_template('appuntamenti.html', form1=form1, appuntamenti=appuntamenti)
    else:
        cursor.close()
        return render_template('appuntamenti.html', form1=form1)

#HERE IS WHERE THE POST SHOULD BE
@app.route("/modify_appointment",methods=["POST"])
def modify_appointment():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        getid = request.form['id']
        new_date = request.form['new_date']
        new_date = parser.parse(new_date)
        cur.execute('UPDATE Appuntamento SET Data = {0} WHERE idAppuntamento = {1}'.format(new_date, getid))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        msg = 'Record deleted successfully'
        return jsonify(msg)
```

**What the form actually does:**

```
GET /?startdate=2022-06-21T11%3A11&submit=Submit HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitted via GET because the form's default behavior is used and no method attribute is specified. Calling your JavaScript function on a submit event will be ignored.
To avoid this, you should pass the event object to the function and call [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) which signals the browser to suppress the default action for this event. So you can send the form data with AJAX.

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="modify_event(event)">
    <!-- Your code here! -->
</form>

<script>
function modify_event(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  /* Your code here! */
}
</script>
```

To reset the value of the input field, you can either assign a new value to the property value of the input field, or you [reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) the entire form. With the latter, the input field is assigned the value that was set after loading.

```
event.target.reset()
```

Comment: Turns out I did this before but had an error in my query, thanks a lot :) ! Anyway if I am not asking and disturbing you too much, is there any way to reset the value of  {{ form.startdate }}  after I am done? in this way the modal won't show the old value

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly.